# Query multiple meta key values for template

Tags: wp-query, mysql

I am using this template:
http://demo.undsgn.com/studiofolio/front-page/

I tried to make some modifications because I need the homepage template to display an excerpt beneath each thumbnail. I copied the template called `front-page.php`, renamed it to `front-page-excerpt.php` and made my modifications and it worked.

The problem is there is a framework behind it that controls which template is shown on the homepage. The framework is: http://aquagraphite.com/2011/09/slightly-modded-options-framework/

In the backend it looks like this:

[image]
[image]

In the backend my new template isn't showing up, and I think I found the problem. The template is called in the backend options panel like this:

```
    $querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_page_template' 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'templates/front-page.php' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'page'";

    $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

When I change it to:

```
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'templates/front-page-excerpt.php'
```

My modified templates show up, but the original templates are not displayed. I tried to put both in it like this:

```
    $querystr = "  
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta, $wpdb->postmeta AS mt1
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 

    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_page_template'   
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'templates/front-page.php'
    AND mt1.meta_key = '_wp_page_template'
    AND mt1.meta_value = 'templates/front-page-excerpt.php'

    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'page'";

    $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

It doesn't work at all.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That theme appears to be a commercial theme, mean the source code is unavailable and testing is all but impossible. That makes this question off-topic. Try to contact the theme developers.

Comment: thanks rachel . you are right but to this modification the developers give no support and i need thins layout changes very urgently . if u want i can send you my theme for testing . hahahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why you're using clunky custom SQL, use a [meta query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) instead.

```
$pageposts = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
                'key'   => '_wp_page_template',
                'value' => array(
                    'templates/front-page-excerpt.php',
                    'templates/front-page.php',
                )
            )       
        ),  
    )
);
```

Comment: perfect that worked !!! Thanks so much ! I didnt made it that way because i dont understand the code . hahah

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select both template, you should use OR and not AND operator

```
$querystr = "  
SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta, $wpdb->postmeta AS mt1
WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 

AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_page_template'   
OR $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'templates/front-page.php')
AND mt1.meta_key = '_wp_page_template'
AND mt1.meta_value = 'templates/front-page-excerpt.php'

AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'page'";

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Matthieu. I think we getting closer. 
I didnt understand why but now it shows each and EVERYPAGE ever made in the options panel . why that? it filters it with our 2 meta_values right!? but it shows every page which are not front-page.php or front-page-excerpt.php.

funny fact: if there is only a page applied to front-page.php ist showing nothing in the panel sidebar . when i apply a page to front-page-excerpt.php it shows everypage.

Do you think we gettin this right ?

Comment: maby important this code appears in two files 1 ind theme-options.php and a second time ind base.php